# in jade, arguments passed to a `mixin` have unevaluated variables

Tags: node.js, pug

when an argument to a `mixin` that contains a variable, it is apparently not evaluated.

for example,

```
mixin js( out, lcl )
  if suffix == 'out'
    script( src= net )
  else
    script( src= lcl )

mixin js( "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/headjs/0.99/head.load.min.js",   "http://trailsandtribulations.#{suffix}/scripts/head.load.min.js" );
```

yields

```
<script src="http://trailsandtribulations.#{suffix}/scripts/head.load.min.js">
```

But the variable `suffix` works normally

for example,

```
script( src="http://trailsandtribulations.#{suffix}/scripts/head.load.min.js" )
```

yields

```
<script src="http://trailsandtribulations.nat/scripts/head.load.min.js">
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: pure js is not evaluated

Comment: @user1737909 - if so, how does one write / use the mixin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following @user1737909 lead,

changed to

```
script( src="http://trailsandtribulations."+suffix+"/scripts/head.load.min.js" )
```

and it worked

this probably makes sense, but it doesn't make sense in a universe that makes sense to me

things like generating <script> fragments with `mixins` would be cool, for example, but far beyond my reach and understanding